# Is there any proper way to fill equally labels in stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I need to layout my labels like this: [image]

But i'm getting this layout:
[image]

If I add spaces between two labels, then they all move out:

Here's view hierarchy:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by putting label into the view container.

Answer (score 1):

Name three labels “left”, “centre” and “right” for understanding purpose for now.

Put all three labels inside Horizontal Stack View

Set StackView both settings to “Fill”

Now let’s fix labels

- left label

  - content hugging priority - Horizontal : 1000
  - Aspect ratio - 1:1
  - Text Alignment - Centre
- right label

  - content hugging priority - Horizontal : 1000

Comment: This will do basic UI placement.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Distribution` property of `UIStackView` to `Fill Equally` on the `Attributes Inspector` tab on the right side. And modify the text alignment of the leading label to leading and the trailing label to trailing.